# How do you know which MetaMask is real or are they both?

Tags: browser-addons

So I was checking out a new dapp, and instead of the usual notification from MetaMask, a pop-up opened instead. The contents are virtually identical to the plugin dropdown, but I thought MetaMask always behaved the same till now.  I will review my browser settings to insure that pop-ups are disabled, but it made me wary and wondering if a clever developer could create a pop-up to capture MetaMask passwords.  How can people be 100% certain which MetaMask is real or if one is just a website accumulating wallet passwords?
[image]

Comment: Assuming the browser you're on works in the same or similar manner as chromium ones, you can likely use Developer Settings to achieve this (if not, maybe [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or equivalent)?  You'll have to research the exact procedure for your browser, or hopefully someone else is able to help you out here.